# Set last `n` bits in unsigned int

Tags: c++, c, gcc, bitwise-operators

How to set (in most elegant way) exactly `n` least significant bits of `uint32_t`? That is to write a function `void setbits(uint32_t *x, int n);`. Function should handle each `n` from `0` to `32`.

Especially value `n==32` should be handled.

Comment: by last do you mean high order or low order?

Comment: this question handles any values in the range \[0, 64\]: [Creating a mask with N least significant bits set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52573447/995714)

Comment: "by last do you mean high order or low order?" -- the question specifies the *least significant* bits, i.e., "low order".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you meant the least-significant n bits:

```
((uint32_t)1 << n) - 1
```

On most architectures, this won't work if n is 32, so you may have to make a special case for that:

```
n == 32 ? 0xffffffff : (1 << n) - 1
```

On a 64-bit architecture, a (probably) faster solution is to cast up then down:

```
(uint32_t)(((uint64_t)1 << n) - 1)
```

In fact, this might even be faster on a 32-bit architecture since it avoids branching.

Comment: @Marcelo: I guess it works even without u64 test, just the first version, doesn't it?

Comment: @TonyK: No, it doesn't work, because shifting a 32-bit integer by 32-bits isn't supported on most architectures (certainly not on Intel).

Comment: Right:  "The behavior is undefined if the right operand is...equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand." [C++11 §5.8/1]

Comment: @TonyK n == 32 shifts one past the width, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Marcelo: Anyway, Marcelo, answer accepted. Good to know about 1<<32 issue.

Comment: I don't think that this answer is correct. `1` is of type `int` and `1 << n` could go wrong for much more cases than you assume. A first shot would be to use `1U << n` but then the OP explicitly wanted `uint32_t`. For that the correct thing would be to use `UINT32_C(1) << n`.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Nice. Though I assume you meant `(uint32_t)((-1)>>(32-n))`

Comment: oops. But no, I meant `(uint32_t)`, with signed it will stay with all bits set for all values of n.

Comment: I see you edited your guess, still no, I want to cast before shifting.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Other than 32, which has already been discussed, which other value(s) doesn't my answer handle correctly?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Ah, sorry; I misunderstood what you were trying to do. Yes, that works, but it also has an edge-case: n == 0.

Comment: @MarceloCantos, IRC left shift with `31` on an 32 bit integer leads to overflow => undefined behavior. And then `int` is only guaranteed to be 16 bit wide by the standard. In summary your version can fail for values from `16` to `31`.

Comment: @MarceloCantos, also in your faster version, what is the purpose of cast `n` to `uint64_t`? You should "cast" the `1` this is what determines the type of the expression.

Comment: Branching would most probably not be an issue here... there are specific assembly instructions to handle the simpler `cond?a:b` cases like this. Try to compile into assembly and check the output.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Ah yes; good points; I've fixed it. When you said, "much more cases", I thought you meant something more calamitous.

Comment: @MarceloCantos, at least the 31 is calamitous. Please fix it by just putting a `1U` instead of `1` as a base of the shift.

Comment: You can just use `~0UUL` or `~0UL` instead of `0xsomanyf`. It'll be more platform independent as you don't need to know the exact size of `int` or `long` or whatever.

Comment: @xuhdev: The OP stipulated uint32_t.

Comment: If you can't shift all the way through, then shift half of that and then do the rest: (1 << n/2 << n - n/2) - 1 (sort of a joke)

Comment: there are many ways to handle that case without a branch: [Creating a mask with N least significant bits set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52573447/995714)

Answer (score 35):

Here's a method that doesn't require any arithmetic:

```
~(~0u << n)
```

Comment: +1, no memory access, no branches and no special cases. I consider this to be the most elegant solution.

Comment: @DarkDust: Except this (sometimes) fails for n = 32, since shifting a `uint_32t` by `32` is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers don't handle the special case of `n == 32` (shifting by greater than or equal to the type's width is UB), so here's a better answer:

```
(uint32_t)(((uint64_t)1 << n) - 1)
```

Alternatively:

```
(n == 32) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : (((uint32_t)1 << n) - 1)
```

Comment: The other answers handle it perfectly well. (1 << 32) - 1 is 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: @Tony: No they don't.  Shifting beyond the length of the type is undefined.

Comment: @Tony: You're downvoting because I gave an answer containing portable code with well-defined behaviour?

Comment: @TonyK: This has as much to do with the CPU as the compiler, and it doesn't work my i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, casting a constant? This should just be `UINT64_C(1)`. And then your alternative solution doesn't work on architectures with 16 bit `int`, but doesn't work for 32 bit `int` either, because for `31` you have an overflow.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, why casting a constant where the language gives you the right tool to just specify the right one?

Answer (score 5):

```
const uint32_t masks[33] = {0x0, 0x1, 0x3, 0x7 ...

void setbits(uint32_t *x, int n)
{
   *x |= masks[n];
}
```

Comment: Unnecessary amounts of coding, but at least it will give the right answer.

Comment: @TJD: I guess unnecessary amount of memory access.

Answer (score 1):

If n is zero then no bits should be set based on the question.

```
const uint32_t masks[32] = {0x1, 0x3, 0x7, ..., 0xFFFFFFFF};

void setbits(uint32_t *x, int n)
{
    if ( (n > 0) && (n <= 32) )
    {
        *x |= masks[--n];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Goals:

- no branches (including parameter check of n)
- no 64-bit conversions

```
void setbits(uint32_t *x, unsigned n) {
    // As @underscore_d notes in the comments, this line is
    // produces Undefined Behavior for values of n greater than
    // 31(?). I'm ok with that, but if you're code needs to be
    // 100% defined or you're using some niche, little-used
    // compiler (perhaps for a microprocesser?), you should
    // use `if` statements. In fact, this code was just an
    // an experiment to see if we could do this in only 32-bits
    // and without any `if`s. 
    *x |= (uint32_t(1) << n) - 1;
    // For any n >= 32, set all bits. n must be unsigned
    *x |= -uint32_t(n>=32);
}
```

Note: if you need `n` to be of type `int`, add this to the end:

```
    // For any n<=0, clear all bits
    *x &= -uint32_t(n>0);
```

Explanation:

```
    *x |= -uint32_t(n>=32);
```

When `n>=32` is true, `x` will be bitwise-ORed with 0xFFFFFFFF, yielding an `x` with all bits set.

```
    *x &= -uint32_t(n>0);
```

This line states that as long as any bit should be set, `n>0`, bitwise-AND `x` with 0xFFFFFFFF which will result in no change to `x`. If `n<=0`, `x` will be bitwise-ANDed with 0 and consequently result in a value of 0.

Sample program to show the algorithm works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void print_hex(int32_t n) {
  uint32_t x = (uint32_t(1) << n);
  printf("%3d:  %08x  |%08x  |%08x  &%08x\n",
         n, x, x - 1,
         -uint32_t(n>=32),
         -uint32_t(n>0));
}

void print_header() {
  //        1:  00000002  |00000001  |00000000  &ffffffff
  printf("  n:   1 << n    (1<<n)-1   n >= 32     n <= 0\n");
}

void print_line() {
  printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
}

int main() {
  print_header();
  print_line();
  for (int i=-2; i<35; i++) {
    print_hex(i);
    if (i == 0 || i == 31) {
      print_line();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output (broken up and annotated):

For `n < = 0`, the last step ANDs with 0 ensuring the result is 0.

```
  n:   1 << n    (1<<n)-1   n >= 32     n <= 0
---------------------------------------------
 -2:  40000000  |3fffffff  |00000000  &00000000
 -1:  80000000  |7fffffff  |00000000  &00000000
  0:  00000001  |00000000  |00000000  &00000000
```

For `1 <= n <= 31`, the last two steps "OR 0, AND 0xffffffff" result in no change to the number. The only step that matters is the "OR (1<

```
  n:   1 << n    (1<<n)-1   n >= 32     n <= 0
---------------------------------------------
  1:  00000002  |00000001  |00000000  &ffffffff
  2:  00000004  |00000003  |00000000  &ffffffff
  3:  00000008  |00000007  |00000000  &ffffffff
  4:  00000010  |0000000f  |00000000  &ffffffff
  5:  00000020  |0000001f  |00000000  &ffffffff
  6:  00000040  |0000003f  |00000000  &ffffffff
  7:  00000080  |0000007f  |00000000  &ffffffff
  8:  00000100  |000000ff  |00000000  &ffffffff
  9:  00000200  |000001ff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 10:  00000400  |000003ff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 11:  00000800  |000007ff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 12:  00001000  |00000fff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 13:  00002000  |00001fff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 14:  00004000  |00003fff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 15:  00008000  |00007fff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 16:  00010000  |0000ffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 17:  00020000  |0001ffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 18:  00040000  |0003ffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 19:  00080000  |0007ffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 20:  00100000  |000fffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 21:  00200000  |001fffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 22:  00400000  |003fffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 23:  00800000  |007fffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 24:  01000000  |00ffffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 25:  02000000  |01ffffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 26:  04000000  |03ffffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 27:  08000000  |07ffffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 28:  10000000  |0fffffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 29:  20000000  |1fffffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 30:  40000000  |3fffffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
 31:  80000000  |7fffffff  |00000000  &ffffffff
```

For `n >= 32`, all bits should be set and the "OR ffffffff" step accomplishes that regardless of what the previous step may have done. The `n <= 0` step is then a noop as well with `AND ffffffff`.

```
  n:   1 << n    (1<<n)-1   n >= 32     n <= 0
---------------------------------------------
 32:  00000001  |00000000  |ffffffff  &ffffffff
 33:  00000002  |00000001  |ffffffff  &ffffffff
 34:  00000004  |00000003  |ffffffff  &ffffffff
```

Comment: Your case for `n >= 32` does not help, since the prior unchecked shift will still be done, and if `n >= sizeof(TheType) * CHAR_BIT`, that's UB, which isn't affected by whether you try to paper over it after the fact.

Comment: Perhaps "goals" should also include "readable/understandable code" :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Yeah, that's why I stated the goals: to indicate that readable code was NOT the goal. :)

Comment: @underscore_d What's "UB" mean? It's ok if the first line is produces a bad value for `n>=32` because the next line corrects it. I've added a program to the answer that proves the algorithm. Honestly, it has been so long that I needed the program to prove it to myself.

Comment: @Harvey Undefined behaviour poisons the entirety of a program as soon as you invoke it. You cannot "correct it" by overwriting it afterwards. And it means absolutely nothing if you find that the code *happens* to produce the correct results when tested, because the UB means that it's not **required** to and can break at any time (when ported to a different architecture, compiler, Standard revision, etc.). Code that invokes UB is bad and shouldn't be posted as a recommendation, and that's the end of it.

Comment: @underscore_d I get your point, and I respectfully disagree. Example: `x = uint32_t(1) << 40; x = 7;` Even if the first statement is undefined behavior (for some values, e.g. 40), the second line is very much defined behavior and the result is ok. Unless "undefined behavior" includes crashing an app or memory corruption, it's good.

Comment: @underscore_d To be fair, I was surprised that `<<` doesn't mean shift for my current compiler. It clearly means shift with rotation which I wouldn't have expected (undefined behavior).

Comment: @Harvey There's nothing to disagree about. The letter of the Standard is that once UB occurs, the behaviour of the entire program is undefined. It doesn't matter if you then do something that completely replaces the object; UB has occurred, and it can't be undone. Sure, practically, probably nothing will go wrong, as compilers don't make it their mission to ruin your life. But it's formally ill-formed code, so it's irresponsible to portray it as being fine.

Comment: @underscore_d I agree with you in principle. In this case, I'm ok with this specific code because I think "undefined behavior" probably means "undefined, but sane". In other words, no compiler writer is going to guarantee that the value returned is what you expected, but they will probably guarantee not to modify anything other than that value producing no side effects. I'll add a comment with your warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the most significant n bits:

```
-1 ^ ((1 << (32 - n)) - 1)
```

Comment: The `-1 ^` part is the same as a NOT operation, so just use `~((1 << (32 - n)) - 1)`

Answer (score -1):

```
((((1 << (n - 1)) - 1) << 1) | 1)
```

Set last n bits. n must be > 0. Work with n = 32.

Comment: From the question: "Function should handle each n from 0 to 32"