# How to calculate the sum of a sequence of powers of 2 in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I want to calculate a sequence of exponents of base 2. for example if given 3 the program would calculate (2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0). The problem is I cant calculate the exponent to being with.

I have tried `shl` to calculate the exponent and I have tried a loop.  Neither produce the correct result, my latest attempt is below.

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
INCLUDE io.h                            
.STACK 4096

.DATA

        Exponent    DWORD   ?           
        Prompt  BYTE    "Enter an exponent", 0

        Base        DWORD  2

        string      BYTE    40 DUP (?)

        resultLbl   BYTE    "The solution is", 0
        Solution    DWORD   20 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC

    input   Prompt, string, 40      ; read ASCII characters (N)
        atod    string              ; ascii to double
        mov     exponent, eax       ; store in memory     


        push Exponent
        push Base

        call function
        add esp, 8

        dtoa   Solution, eax         ; convert to ASCII characters
        output  resultLbl, Solution   ; output label and sum



                mov     eax, 0      ; exit with return code 0
        ret

_MainProc ENDP


;@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
; Procedure takes base and exponent from main

Function PROC
    push ebp                      ; stores base pointer
    mov  ebp, esp                 ; set base pointer to current position

    mov ebx, [ebp + 12]   ; read base (2)
    mov ecx,  [ebp + 8]       ; read N



    MainLoop:           ; loop to calculate expoent
          mul ebx           ; multiply base by its self
          add eax, ebx           ; save answer in eax
          dec ecx                ; decrement the exponent
          cmp ecx, 0             ; check if exponent is 0 yet
          je exit                ; Exit if exponent is 0
          jg mainloop            ; stay in loop if exponent is above 0

    Exit: 

        pop ebp                   ; restore base pointer 
        ret

function ENDP



END
```

I want the program to produce the correct exponent result, and if you can calculate the sequence above, for example if given 3 the program would calculate (2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0).

Comment: Consult the instruction set reference about how `mul` works. Hint: it puts result in `eax` (and `edx`) so your `add eax, ebx` is pointless. Pick a different target register **and** add `eax` to it. Also you forgot to initialize `eax` so you are just multiplying some random number. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 = 2^4-1, 2^n + 2^(n-1) + ... + 2^1 + 2^0 = 2^(n+1) - 1

Comment: Your edit destroyed most of the question, now it's just asking about an integer power loop, not a *sum* of powers, and not specifically powers of 2 anymore.  And you didn't even link or describe the Microsoft doc you found.  Rolling it back.  If you want to post the link in a comment, go ahead.  (Link-only *answers* are not welcome on stack overflow, so if you want to post an answer it has to be at least a minimal answer on its own in case the link rots.)

Answer (score 4):

Base 2 is an extremely special case because computers use binary integers.

`2^n = 1 << n`  i.e. 2<sup>n</sup> = 1 left-shifted `n` times.  i.e. that bit-position is set.

You're asking for `2^0 + 2^1 + ... 2^n`.  **A number with all bits set up to an including bit `n`.**
That's 1 less than `2^(n+1)`, so the number you want is **`2^(n+1) - 1`**.

---

**x86 has an instruction to set a bit at a given position in a register: [`bts reg, reg` = Bit Test and Set](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bts).**  On Intel CPUs, the reg-reg form decodes to a single uop, with 1-cycle latency. (https://agner.org/optimize/)  It also puts the old value of the bit in CF, but normally we don't care about that when using it for this.  Normally we just zero a destination register and use BTS to set a single bit.

On Ryzen, `bts reg,reg` is 2 uops and variable-count shifts are single-uop, so `mov edx, 1` / `shl edx, cl` is good, too.  But that's worse for code-size, and more uops on Intel CPUs.

On Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs, [`shl reg, cl`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sal:sar:shl:shr) decodes to 3 uops.  BMI2 [`shlx reg, reg, reg`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sarx:shlx:shrx) is 1 uop, but BMI2 support is still far from being something you can assume, unfortunately.

(Memory-destination BTS with a register source is very slow, treating the source as an indexing into an arbitrary length bit-string, not just the addressed dword, so normally avoid it for performance.)

---

#### Calculating `2^(n+1) - 1` without overflow

([C version of this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573447/creating-a-mask-with-n-least-significant-bits-set/56511578#56511578), with compiler output.)

If we just added 1 to the input number before feeding it to BTS, it could wrap around and fail to work for `31` (which should set all bits, but would instead set bit `32%32 = 0`)

Since we need one extra instruction after reading the input anyway, we can use x86's shift-and-add instruction (LEA) to do one more shift *as* we subtract 1.  So with `n=31` we start with the high bit set, and shift it out to get zero.  Subtracting 1 then sets all the bits, as desired

```
xor    edx,edx                 ; edx = 0
bts    edx, eax                ; edx |=  1<<eax
lea    edx, [edx + edx - 1]    ; edx = (edx<<1) - 1
```

The logic for this goes as follows

```
n      BTS result (2^n)    *2 - 1
0    ->       1         ->   1        = 2 - 1
1    ->       2         ->   3        = 4 - 1
2    ->       4         ->   7        = 8 - 1
3    ->       8         ->  15        = 16 - 1
...
30   ->  0x40000000     ->  0x7FFFFFFF  = 0x80000000 - 1
31   ->  0x80000000     ->  0xFFFFFFFF  = 0 - 1
```

It's not a coincidence that the last column is a running total of the 2nd column.

LEA with 3 "components" to the addressing mode has extra latency vs. simpler LEAs, e.g. 3-cycle latency on Sandybridge-family vs. 1 cycle.  But it's still a single uop so it's a great choice for throughput.

If we really wanted to optimize, *and didn't have to worry about the `n=31` case overflowing*, we'd write the ASCII -> int loop by hand but start with a total of `1` instead of `0`, to fold the `n+1` into finding `n`.  Then  `bts` would give us our `2^(n+1)`, and we could simply `dec` that.

---

There's no need to store `exponent` to memory and reload it again; you already have it in a register where you want it.

Your comment on the `atod` line is wrong, and your code wouldn't make sense if it was right.  ASCII to `double` (like the C function `strtod`) would return in x87 `st0` or SSE2 `xmm0`, not EAX.  `atod` actually stands for ASCII (decimal) to integer.  Perhaps the `d` stands for DWORD.

```
    input   Prompt, string, 40      ; read ASCII characters (N)
    atod    string                 ; ascii (decimal) to integer in EAX

    xor    edx,edx                 ; edx = 0
    bts    edx, eax                ; edx |=  1<<eax
    lea    edx, [edx + edx - 1]    ; edx = (edx<<1) - 1

    dtoa    Solution, edx
```

It takes 2 instructions to implement `1<<n` so it's silly to put it into its own function.  Just passing args + calling the function would have take as much work as simply using `bts`.

```
0 -> 1 -> 1
1 -> 2 -> 3
2 -> 4 -> 7
```

---

Compilers typically use `mov edx,1` + `mov ecx, eax` + `shl edx, cl`.  But that's a missed optimization, especially on Intel CPUs.

BMI2 `shlx edx, edx, ecx` would help (avoiding the `mov`), but is worse code-size than `xor`-zero + `bts`.  And BMI2 isn't always available.

If you can't get your compiler to use BTS (or you have BMI2 for SHLX), another good implementation is `(2ULL << n) - 1` so you bake the extra shift into the number you start shifting.  So a count of `31` can shift the bit out and produce 0.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: thanks, fixed to clean up all that rambling guesswork and just explain that it's not `double`.

Comment: You should add common x86 math instructions to ppcg x86 tips. Also isn't the shortcut computation 2^(n+1) - 1

Comment: @qwr: IMO [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981) is cluttered enough with things that are only relevant to size optimization.  I don't think we should write answers for every micro-optimization that compilers already do for performance reasons.  (Although compilers do often miss BTS.)

Comment: @qwr: oh right, the question title misled me, they are asking about the sum of all powers of 2, not just one power of 2.

Comment: is this correct: xor + bts is 1+3 bytes, xor + inc + shl is 1+1+2 bytes?

Comment: @qwr: no, xor reg,reg is 2 bytes.  BTS is 3.  SHL reg,cl is 2 bytes.  (Creating an arbitrary small constant costs 3 bytes, e.g. with push imm8/pop, LEA from a known constant, or xor-zero + inc/dec).  Anyway, fixed my answer to do `2^(n+1)-1` safely with only 1 more instruction!  This answer is not attempting to focus on code-golf, only code-size as a tie-breaker when performance is equal.

Comment: there are many ways to calculate `2^(n+1) - 1` without overflow in [Creating a mask with N least significant bits set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52573447/995714)

Comment: @phuclv: those are all more complicated and thus worse if we don't need `0` as a possible output.  But it's an interesting related problem.  I posted a (non-)answer there using this trick because it's highly related.  I should really submit a bug report to GCC and clang about using BTS; it's missed optimization that seems to come up fairly often, especially for `x |= 1<<n;` where it's even more of a missed opt.