# Set n least significant bits to 1

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to set the first N bits of a register to 1. For example, if N is 3 then the register would be: `...00000111`. Is there an instruction or short-form way to do this? The way I'm currently doing it is:

```
   mov $0, %eax
   test %esi, %esi
   jz end
 loop:
   add $0b1, %eax
   dec %esi
   jz end_loop
   shl %eax
   jmp loop
  exit:
    ...
```

Comment: Powers of 2 have the pattern `00100000`.  Subtract one from that and you get `00011111`, for example.

Comment: @ErikEidt so that would be three instructions then like Nate shows below? Or can you do it in less than a `load 1` `shift left` `subtract 1` ?

Comment: Do you want to *shift in* 3 `1` bits into an existing register?  If not, the normal way to set bits is with OR, because it doesn't care about their previous value.

Comment: If the amount is a constant, you can precompute the value, i.e. use your slide rule to compute it and type that number into the program so it doesn't have to do the math at runtime.

Comment: @PeterCordes could you please clarify what you mean about "shift in 3" bits? Do you mean like doing `xor %eax, %eax` `or %eax 0b111` ?

Comment: I mean if you have an existing register containing `ABCDEFGH`, you could get a result like  `DEFGH111`.  Like you were doing 1 bit at a time starting with zero.  But yes, of course the better way is just `shl $3, %eax` / `or $(1<<3) - 1, %eax` if you had some existing register and wanted to shift in ones instead of zeros.  (BTW, your last edit make your loop a lot clunkier and less efficient, when you could have fixed your bug by doing the shift *before* the add.  Or for example `lea 1(%rax, %rax), %eax` to shift-and-add in one instruction.  Of course going 1 bit at a time is pointless anyway)

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for pointing that out -- yea I was curious about how to do the first shift-left which seemed pretty clunky/confusing for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A useful mathematical fact is that a value with N low-order 1 bits is 1 less than a power of two, which you can get by shifting.  So you can simply load the count into `%cl` and do

```
mov $1, %eax
shl %cl, %eax
dec %eax
```

Of course if the count N is a constant known at assembly time, then let the assembler do the math and just load the result:

```
mov $((1 << N) - 1), %eax
```

Comment: That's so cool, thanks for the clear explanation. Does `$((1 << N) - 1)` work in gas, or what assembler is that?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: Yes, gas understands arithmetic on integer constants using C-like syntax.  See https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Integer-Exprs.html#Integer-Exprs

Comment: @NateEldredge: a more efficient way (on Intel at least) to create `2^N` for runtime-variable N is `xor %eax,%eax` / `bts %ecx, %eax`.  Then yes, `dec` that.  It fails for N=32, producing 0 instead of 0xFFFFFFFF, same as your shift method, but otherwise is identical.  AMD might actually do better with mov-immediate / shl if your shift count happens to already be in ECX.

Comment: @NateEldredge got it, thank you. Are there other numbers like `2^n` where the result can be calculated with a sort of trick?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: Powers of 2 are special because computers store numbers in binary.  Related: https://catonmat.net/low-level-bit-hacks - you can do a lot of neat stuff with carry or borrow propagation through a contiguous group of 1 or 0 bits (respectively).

Comment: @NateEldredge: The book "Hacker's Delight" discusses some integer tricks.

Comment: `or $-1, %eax` `shl %cl, %eax` `not %eax` is another way to do it and produces shorter code.

Comment: note that this only works if cl < 32. To make it work for any values <= 32 see [Creating a mask with N least significant bits set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52573447/995714)